# Structure of Variable Merge Tags in MailChimp

Tags: variables, merge, mailchimp, meta-tags, mailmerge

I'm attempting to display 12 different images depending on the number of transactions a subscriber has made.  Following the documentation on Mailchimp about their IF: ELSE: tags I have created this:

```
*|IF:TRANSACTIONS > 0|* one *|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS > 1|* two *|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS > 2|* three *|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS > 3|* four *|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS > 4|* five *|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS > 5|* six *|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS > 6|* seven *|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS > 7|* eight *|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS > 8|* nine *|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS > 9|* ten *|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS > 10|* eleven *|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS > 11|* twelve *|ELSE:|* other *|END:IF|*
```

but unfortunately, it doesn't work.  I'm testing on multiple email addresses which each have differing order counts, so I can tell that it's not working.

Any advice on correcting this would be extremely valued.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a Merge Field called TRANSACTIONS (which actually seems long for a merge field name, try ORDERS) and that it is defined as a NUMBER type and not a string or anything else.

Make sure its being set correctly in the audience.

The code you've written seems ok.